# Continuous text in flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview, singlechildscrollview

I want create text with always auto scroll(like label `.continuous` property in `swift`). Now I am using `SingleChildScrollView` with `scrollController`

`SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3), curve: Curves.easeIn);
    });`

Comment: ,please check the below solution and let me know in case of concen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Marquee` property for auto move text in flutter , for it there is library to do so please check it once [Marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/marquee) library

And please check the code for it

```
Marquee(
  text: 'Some sample text that takes some space.',
  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  scrollAxis: Axis.horizontal,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  blankSpace: 20.0,
  velocity: 100.0,
  pauseAfterRound: Duration(seconds: 1),
  startPadding: 10.0,
  accelerationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  accelerationCurve: Curves.linear,
  decelerationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  decelerationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
)
```

Comment: Thank you it's works. But Can I use this without parent ``height``?

Comment: Happy to help you man!!! Please do upvote it also..Yes you can..You can also use the Mediaquey for setting height or width of any widget

Comment: Like for setting the height of any widget be like **Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                  child:**